# How can I pass individual values from a string[] to the XDocument.Load Stream?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, xpath, linq-to-xml

I have this code:

```
namespace ReadXMLfromFile
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            string path = args[0];

            Console.WriteLine("Looking in Directory: " + path);
            Console.WriteLine("Files in Directory:");

            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml");
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(file));
            }

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(???????);

            var spec = doc.XPathSelectElement("project/triggers/hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger/spec").Value;

            //Write to the console

            Console.Write(spec);
            ....
```

I'm writing a program that looks at multiple XML files in a single directory and pulls out XML Elements.

I want to be able to use each filename value in the string array and pass them to the XDocument.Load() so that I can write all the extractions in the console.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to load the XML from all of the files?

Comment: I think you want to move the three lines starting with `XDocument` inside the foreach loop and have `XDocument.Load()` load each file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've done most of the work already. You need to pass the string uri's one by one to `XDocument.Load`:

```
foreach (string path in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.xml", SearchOptions.AllDirectories))
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
    var spec = doc.XPathSelectElement("project/triggers/
                                       hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger/spec").Value;  

    // Do something with spec.
}
```